# Add chat stuff to EACH stack exchange site

Tags: feature-request, chat, design

It would be very convenient to have a link or a list of links to related chat rooms on each of the stack exchange sites. It is a little bit of a hassle to go 'digging' for all the right ones all of the time; not to mention, there are often many chat rooms dedicated to the same thing, so it would be very nice to see them all listed in one area. It would also be very useful for asking for advice on questions in the chat room while asking your question.

**NOTE:** when I mean `'a link to a chat room'`, I do not mean `'a link to a list of links to chat rooms'`. -- Like what Stack has already implemented.

I thought it would also be nice to have a chat box feature added to stack. This way it minimalizes all of the nonsense on the right side of chat rooms, and it makes chatting on stack a lot more convenient.

Comment: This sounds interesting... I like it, but I can imagine it might take a lot to push this on "EACH" stackexchange site. Not to mention that adding a chat box may slow down the page, but I think the concept is cool. It would be one feature that most "question" sites will lack.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

Right there on the homepage, the two recently active chatrooms on the site. It's just not so high up due to other stuff. But it's there.